# Elasticsearch Special Character Issue

Tags: java, search, elasticsearch

Can any one give the Number of Special Character in the Elasticsearch??

Like I found "\". This will yield search parse exception at the Elasticsearch Level.

Any More List Like this so that I can handle that before in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The reserved characters are: + - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /

More info you may find [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters)